# zuordnen zu den oder in den Klassen?

Tags: grammar

Ich habe ein Problem mit dem folgenden Satz:

> Das beschriebene Problem **lässt sich den Klassen der Gruppierungs- und Reihenfolgeprobleme zuordnen**, die zur klassischen kombinatorischen Optimierungsproblemen gehören.

ich habe das Gefühl, dass irgendwas nicht stimmt. Der Satz klingt irgendwie komisch. Ist der Satz grammatikalisch richtig?

Comment: Geht es um 'zu den Klassen' vs. 'in den Klassen' zuordnen, oder um 'läßt sich den Klassen zuordnen' vs. 'zu den Klassen zuordnen'? Überschrift und Text laufen da in unterschiedliche Richtungen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lassen wir mal einfach die Adjektive weg und nutzen für Klasse Einzahl, dann wird es übersichtlicher:

> Das Problem lässt sich (zu) **der** Klasse der Reihenfolgeprobleme zuordnen, die **zu den** Optimierungsproblemen gehören.

"Zur" war falsch. Es wäre richtig bei z. B. Einzahl/weiblich, etwa "zur Ordnungsproblematik gehören". Gerade wenn man in einem solchen Satz ein Wort ändert, passieren einem immer wieder Fehler.
"Zu der" und "der" geht beides, ich halte *der* für besser, da man ja bereits "**zu**ordnet".

Comment: Ich glaube die Frage war, ob 'zu den' oder 'in den'.

Answer (score 2):

Hier überschneiden sich wohl zwei Begriffe.

*etwas einer Klasse **zu**ordnen* und *etwas **in** eine Klasse **ein**ordnen*.

*etwas **zu** einer Klasse **zu**ordnen* existiert auch noch (siehe Verodomon's Antwort), wirkt auf mich aber eher umgangssprachlich.

In im ersten Fall halte ich es für sinnvoller, die Klasse im Singular zu belassen, da *zuordnen* direkter ist:

> Das beschriebene Problem lässt sich **der Klasse /den Klassen** der Gruppierungs- und Reihenfolgeprobleme **zuordnen**, die **zu den** klassischen kombinatorischen Optimierungsproblemen gehören.

bzw:

> Das beschriebene Problem lässt sich **in** **die Klasse /den Klassen** der Gruppierungs- und Reihenfolgeprobleme **einordnen**, die **zu den** klassischen kombinatorischen Optimierungsproblemen gehören.

Comment: Das zweite Beispiel im Plural ist falsch. *... läßt sich den Klassen ... einordnen ...* - Da musst du nochmal bei.

Comment: @tofro das **in** ist beiden Varianten - Singular und Plural - zugehörig gedacht.

Answer (score 1):

> ... die zu den ... gehören.

*Gehören* has to be followed by a *zu* and a dative.